# How to restore Windows 11 terminal properties

Tags: terminal, windows-11, appearance

Last Friday I had a Windows 11 update pushed to my PC.  Now when I open either Cmd or Ubuntu(WSL2), I get some new terminal window that I've never seen before.  I could get used to that, but there are two problems that drive me crazy:

1. The icon changed, with the open window not showing the same icon as the link in my taskbar.  Worse, both Cmd and Ubuntu use the same icon and there's no way to distinguish them.
2. The title bar of the window doesn't change color when I put the focus on the window.  Previously the title would change to the same shade of blue as any other focused window on my system, but now the only indication of focus is a single pixel line around the window - way too subtle to be useful.  I've tried changing the theme but it doesn't help.

Is there any way to restore the previous look?

Here's the old icons on the left and the new icon on the right:

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of how they appear now, to give us a better idea how things have changed?

Comment: @music2myear I can't do a screenshot of the current views without revealing a little too much about my system.  And I no longer have access to the "before" shots for comparison.

Comment: It looks like you're dealing with the new Terminal app replacing CMD. The icon on the right is just the Terminal app, a pretty good tabbed terminal that can do all the interpreters: CMD, PS, anything else too. I don't know how/whether changing app icons differs from changing icons for other traditional apps. Title bar changing color on focus/unfocus is usually a theme setting, not an application setting, though how the app implements OS windowing functions may play a part, but that's unlikely to be something you would have any control over.

Comment: WSL (your "Ubuntu") is almost definitely integrated into Terminal. To open Ubuntu or another specific terminal directly, right-click on the Terminal app and you'll be presented with a list of all the terminals configured in that app, which should include Ubuntu.

Comment: The icon in question, is the icon for Windows Terminal, which is the default terminal handler on Windows 11.  WSL should work flawlessly with it. If it's not working then your Windows Terminal profile for WSL is simply corrupt.  You can reset the Windows Terminal application to restore the default Windows Terminal profiles

Comment: You have perhaps fallen to [PowerShell is replacing Command Prompt](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powershell-is-replacing-command-prompt-fdb690cf-876c-d866-2124-21b6fb2). Try the fix from this link to undo it.

Comment: @harrymc your link is broken.  I found a page with a similar title but it didn't help.

Comment: @Ramhound oh it works just fine, my problems are purely cosmetic and are listed in the question.

Comment: Windows Terminal has changed going forward with the last update. I forget exactly where I read this but I did read it. You can get a different look for cmd.exe but it has changed and so far as I know permanently so. The old cmd.exe look is still available in Windows 10.

Comment: The old icon existing on Windows 10 isn’t very helpful